# How to add missing cjk characters?

Tags: cjk

I am making Georgian/Japanese document, and I noticed that some characters are missing, such as ゔ - which is "v" in hiragana. How can the missing characters be added to the documents?

the sample of my code is:

```
\documentclass[8pt]{article}
\input{glyphtounicode} 
\pdfgentounicode=1 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage[T8K,T8M]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[thaicjk,english,georgian]{babel}

\newcommand{\Ceil}[1]{$\lceil\text{#1}\rfloor$}
\newcommand{\Stoke}[1]{$\left/\text{#1}\right/$}

\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}
っ იეროგლიფი უკან მდგომი მარცვლის ასოს აორმაგებს, მაგალითად ちょっと \Stoke{cho\underline{tto}}--- ცოტა. ぁ, ぃ, ぅ, ぇ, ぉ იეროგლიფები, მსგავსად ゃ, ゅ, ょ, გამოიყენება ახალი მარცვლის ჩასაწერად, მაგალითად: ふぁ გამოითქმის, როგორც \Stoke{fa} და არა როგორც \Stoke{fua}. ანალოგიურად ხდება კატაკანაში: ァ, ィ, ゥ, ェ, ォ, ッ, ャ, ュ, ョ. ამათგარდა ჰირაგანაში არის ゝ, ゞ და კატაკანაში ヽ, ヾ სიმბოლოები, რომლებიც აორმაგებენ მის წინ მდგომ იეროგლიფს, მაგალითად ესენი გვხვდება საკუთარ სახელებში: \underline{さゝ}き \Stoke{\underline{sasa}ki}, \underline{おゝ}の   \Stoke{\underline{oo}no}, い\underline{すゞ} \Stoke{i\underline{suzu}}. კანას დამწერლობაში კიდევ არის რამოდენიმე იეროგლიფი, რაც ხშირად არ გამოიყენება, ესენია: ゔ, ヴ \Stoke{v}, ゐ, ヰ  \Stoke{wi}, ゑ, ヱ \Stoke{we}.
\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

You can leave out Georgian font if you like. In pdf where should be ゔ character is empty space. Also there may be some kanji characters missing because I had compiling problems with Japanese particles Type names (格助詞, 並立助詞,...).

For compiling I am using pdflatex in texlive (linux). Also it would be great if someone knows how to run this exact code in miktex (windows).

Answer (score 2):

The Hiragana symbol ゔ (vu) is a relatively recent addition, so that's probably why you cannot see it. Switching to xelatex (at least for this document) will solve your problems. It's also easier to use since you don't need to add any environments.

The difference is that you manually have to set a font. I used Menlo because along with Arial it's the only one I have by default that supports Georgian. But you could use any font that supports the language (you can check beforehand in another WYSIWYG text editor).

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{Hiragino Mincho Pro}
\setmainfont{Menlo}

\begin{document}
\noindent ゔ\\
う\\
格助詞\\
並立助詞\\

\noindent And now some Georgian!\\

\noindent იეროგლიფი უკან მდგომი მარცვლის ასოს აორმაგებს, მაგალითად
\end{document}
```